# Center tablecell with a list structure

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lists

I'm trying to put some lists into a table, which seems harder than I imagined it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering

    \newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,
                        nosep,
                        after=\strut,
                        align=parleft,
                        leftmargin=*,
                        after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                        before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}
    
    \newcommand*{\listone}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{a}
        \item \textit{b}
        \item \textit{c}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
    \newcommand*{\listtwo}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{d}
        \item \textit{e}
        \item \textit{f}
    \end{tabitemize}}

    \newcommand*{\listthree}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{g}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
    \newcommand*{\mergedlist}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{1}
        \item \textit{2}
        \item \textit{3}
        \item \textit{4}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
\begin{tabular}{{P{0.25}P{0.36}P{0.35}}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Row A}  & \textbf{Row B}    & \textbf{Row C}    \\ \midrule
    \listone        & \listtwo          & \listthree        \\ \midrule
                    & \mergedlist       &                   \\
\bottomrule\hline
\end{tabular}
    
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum.}
    \label{tab:some_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table with lists as content]

Now I'm trying to center the list with the numbers in its row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In comparison to your original code, I have replaced `\raggedright` with `\centering` in the definition of the `P` type column. Additionally, I have changed the `before` and `after`keys of the `tabitemize` list in order to place a `minipage` around the list. If the width of the minipage is just wide enough for its contents, the list will appear centered in the column. The appropriate width must be determined manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering

    \newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,
                        nosep,
                        after=\strut,
                        align=parleft,
                        leftmargin=*,
                        after=\end{minipage},
                        before=\begin{minipage}[t]{2em}}
    
    \newcommand*{\listone}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{a}
        \item \textit{b}
        \item \textit{c}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
    \newcommand*{\listtwo}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{d}
        \item \textit{e}
        \item \textit{f}
    \end{tabitemize}}

    \newcommand*{\listthree}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{g}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
    \newcommand*{\mergedlist}{\begin{tabitemize} 
        \item \textit{1}
        \item \textit{2}
        \item \textit{3}
        \item \textit{4}
    \end{tabitemize}}
    
\begin{tabular}{{P{0.25}P{0.36}P{0.35}}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Row A}  & \textbf{Row B}    & \textbf{Row C}    \\ \midrule
    \listone        & \listtwo          & \listthree        \\ \midrule
                    & \mergedlist       &                   \\
\bottomrule\hline
\end{tabular}
    
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum.}
    \label{tab:some_table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```